# Use knockoutjs virtual element to create html part on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to use "virtual element" with html binding to create html part on the fly but failed with message: "The binding 'html' cannot be used with virtual elements". Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3Dpp/.

Anyone knows if there is any workaround?

Comment: Are you saying you want to use templated html to replace a node in the DOM, and that the current `with` and `template` bindings won't work because they only replace their children and not themselves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, after some playing with knockout I see that it is possible.

Working example is here

http://jsfiddle.net/d3Dpp/42/

unfortunatelly this requires duplication of some internal knockout functionality

#### UPDATE

KnockoutJS 2.2.1 added virtual elements binding to export, so it is available even in minified version:

```
ko.exportSymbol('virtualElements.allowedBindings', ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings);
```

It means that better solution for html binding is possible - see [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15348139/1202952).

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: I was just curious to see if the html and vhtml binding could apply the ko bindings recursively and I found it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/d3Dpp/2/

Comment: FYI, KnockoutJS 2.2.1 allows to rid of most of the duplication. Check my answer for code + demo.

Answer (score 9):

Based on Artem's code and KnockoutJS 2.2.1, here's an improved version:

http://jsfiddle.net/YZzDe/2/

Improvements:

1. Less code, less duplication (hooks in to exposed interfaces)
2. Overrides 'html' binding, so basically the old 'html' can now be used in virtuals
3. No more global functions.

Here's the code

```
{
    var overridden = ko.bindingHandlers['html'].update;

    ko.bindingHandlers['html'].update = function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (element.nodeType === 8) {
            var html = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(element);
            if ((html !== null) && (html !== undefined)) {
                if (typeof html !== 'string') {
                    html = html.toString();
                }

                var parsedNodes = ko.utils.parseHtmlFragment(html);
                if (parsedNodes) {
                   var endCommentNode = element.nextSibling;
                   for (var i = 0, j = parsedNodes.length; i < j; i++)
                      endCommentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(parsedNodes[i], endCommentNode);
                }
            }
        } else { // plain node
            overridden(element, valueAccessor);
        }
    };
}
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['html'] = true;
```

Comment: This solved my issue of trying to display a HTML field in a knockout template. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this as your view:

```
<div data-bind="html: html"></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This will replace the innerHtml of the div "container" with your provided html property.

Comment: I know how to use html binding for an existing element. My question is I want to create the element itself on the fly. i.e. I don't want to bind an inner html content for the div or whatever, I want the html content be put in place.