# How change virtual element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How I can change virtual element's property with JavaScript?

```
div#div1::before {
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

I want to change blur effect in above code with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to change a standard css class property simply use `document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style`, which can be found in multiple docs, such as [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).

```
document.getElementById(yourId).style.filter = blur(20px);
```

Functions similarly when selecting by class.

If you wish to directly access css pseudo class before, there is a workaround by adding a `style` element to the `DOM` element and then manipulating it's value. Credit to @RickHitchcock for fixing syntax

```
var cssChange = document.createElement('style');
cssChange.innerHTML= '#div::before {filter: 20px;}';
document.selector.appendChild(cssChange );
```

The other, often cleaner, option is to add a class in your CSS Sheet:

```
.some-class:before {
    filter: blur(20px) !important;
}
```

and then add your class via JS

```
document.selector.addClass('some-class');
```

Keep in mind adding multiple such classes with !important tags to override CSS can get messy as well.

Comment: `append` by itself won't work.  You'll need to create the `style` element then append it as a child of the element.  Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fvehv6oc/

Comment: Thanks @RickHitchcock, I'm sure I have a working example of the append somewhere, but it's late and chances are I messed up the syntax and your solution works well, I have edited the post to include your recomendation

Comment: `append` is a jQuery method, but if you have a non-jQuery example using it, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use KnockoutJS for this purpose.[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679191/use-knockoutjs-virtual-element-to-create-html-part-on-the-fly/15348139#15348139)

For more info regarding KnockoutJS : [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Comment: Anything that can be done in KnockoutJS can also be done in JavaScript.